# Why cant sympy simplify these Sum expressions of Indexed variables

Tags: sympy

Ive hit what seems like a limitation of SymPy. In the middle of trying a small project I notised that SymPy is not able to simplify the following expresison

```
n, N = symbols('n N', cls=Idx)
x = IndexedBase('x')
eq = Sum(x[n], (n, 0, N)) - Sum(x[n], (n, 0, N-1))
simplify(eq)
```

The output is simply

[image]

This should be "simplifyable" to simply X<sub>N</sub>

I've tried to replace both one of and both of `n` and `N` with Symbol(, integer=True), as well as adding all combinations of the assumptions "positive" and "nonzero". I've also tried to make X a function instead

```
N = symbols('N', cls=Idx)
n = Symbol('n')
x = Function('x')

eq = Sum(x(n), (n, 0, N)) - Sum(x(n), (n, 0, N-1))
simplify(eq)
```

Either way SymPy is not able to recognize the possible simplification

Is there any way I can make SymPy be able to do this simplification? Is there an assumption I could add? Is there another function to simplify this?

Update: An issue was opened on the SymPy github asking for implementation of this feature. Any new info will be updated here.

Comment: It might just be that the algorithm for simplifying this sort of case is not implemented. Maybe open an issue on github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19685

Comment: Yes! I opened an issue as suggested. I'll update any new information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments by Oscar Benjamin, this is simply a case of this not being implemented. As per now, I have not found any good way to get around this, so if anyone else is running into the same issue, I suggest simply waiting for an update that implements this, or if this is a deal breaker, trying to find another library that can handle this use case.